# Why won't 'break' work after invalid choice in C++?

Tags: c++

I wrote this code for a rock, paper, scissors game. I think this is all of the relevant code, including the classes used.

```
#ifndef PLAYERH
#define PLAYERH

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

class Player {

public:
    string SetName(string playerName);
    string SetLocation(string PlayerLocation);
    int SetPlayerWins(int playerWins);
    int SetPlayerLosses(double gameCount, int playerTies);
    
    string GetName() const;
    string GetLocation() const;
    int GetPlayerWins() const;
    int GetPlayerLosses() const;
    int GetPlayerTies() const;
    double GetNumGames() const;

private:
    string name;
    string location;
    double games = 0;
    int ties = 0;
    int losses = 0;
    int wins = 0;
    int i;
};
#endif
```

```
#include "Player.h"
using namespace std;

string Player::SetName(string playerName) {
    name = playerName;


    return name;
}

string Player::SetLocation(string playerLocation) {
    location = playerLocation;

    return location;
}

int Player::SetPlayerWins(int playerWins) {
    wins = playerWins;

    return wins;
}

int Player::SetPlayerLosses(double gameCount, int playerTies) {
    games = gameCount;
    ties = playerTies;
    losses = gameCount - wins - ties;

    return losses;
}

string Player::GetName() const {
    return name;
}

string Player::GetLocation() const {
    return location;
}

int Player::GetPlayerWins() const {
    return wins;
}

int Player::GetPlayerLosses() const {
    return losses;
}

int Player::GetPlayerTies() const {
    return ties;
}

double Player::GetNumGames() const {
    return games;
}
```

```
#ifndef ACCESSFILEH
#define ACCESSFILEH

#include "Player.h"

class AccessFile {
public:
    void PrintMatchInfo(Player player1, Player player2);
    void PrintGameInfo(Player player);

private:
    vector<string> players;
    ifstream inFS;
    ofstream outFS;
    string name;
    string fileInfo;
    char nameList;
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    Player winner;

};

#endif
```

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "AccessFile.h"
using namespace std;


void AccessFile::PrintMatchInfo(Player player1, Player player2) {

    cout << "Out of " << player1.GetNumGames() << " match(es): " << endl;
    cout << "Players tied " << player1.GetPlayerTies() << " time(s)." << endl;

    cout << player1.GetName() << " at " << player1.GetLocation() << " has won " << player1.GetPlayerWins();
    cout << " match(es) and lost " << player1.GetPlayerLosses() << " match(es). Their win percentage is ";
    if (player1.GetNumGames() != 0) {
        cout << fixed << setprecision(0) << ((player1.GetPlayerWins() / player1.GetNumGames()) * 100) << "%" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "0%" << endl;
    }

    cout << player2.GetName() << " at " << player2.GetLocation() << " has won " << player2.GetPlayerWins();
    cout << " match(es) and lost " << player2.GetPlayerLosses() << " match(es). Their win percentage is ";
    if (player2.GetNumGames() != 0) {
        cout << fixed << setprecision(0) << ((player2.GetPlayerWins() / player2.GetNumGames()) * 100) << "%" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "0%" << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void AccessFile::PrintGameInfo(Player player) {
    winner = player;
    
    cout << "The players played " << winner.GetNumGames() << " round(s) and the winner is " << winner.GetName() << endl;

}
```

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "AccessFile.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

int player1Choice;
    int player2Choice;
    double gameCount = 0;
    int player1Wins = 0;
    int player2Wins = 0;
    int playerTies = 0;
    Player player1;
    Player player2;
    AccessFile player;
    bool valid = true;

    //Enter player 1 choice
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter 0 for rock, 1 for paper, 2 for scissors, 3 to quit" << endl;
    cout << "Enter player 1 choice: " << endl;
    cin >> player1Choice;
    while (valid != false) {
        //End game if chosen
        if (player1Choice == 3) {
            valid = false;
            break;
        }
        //Play game
        else if (player1Choice >= 0 && player1Choice < 3) {
            //Enter player 2 choice
            cout << "Enter player 2 choice: " << endl;
            cin >> player2Choice;
            //End game if chosen
            if (player2Choice == 3) {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
            //Play game
            while (valid != false) {
                if (player2Choice >= 0 && player2Choice < 3) {
                    gameCount += 1;
                    // Tie
                    if (player1Choice == player2Choice) {
                        cout << "Players have tied." << endl;
                        cout << endl;
                        playerTies += 1;
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    //Player 1 wins
                    else if (player1Choice == 0 && player2Choice != 1) {
                        cout << player1.GetName() << " wins this match." << endl;
                        cout << endl;
                        player1Wins += 1;
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    else if (player1Choice == 1 && player2Choice != 2) {
                        cout << player1.GetName() << " wins this match." << endl;
                        cout << endl;
                        player1Wins += 1;
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    else if (player1Choice == 2 && player2Choice != 0) {
                        cout << player1.GetName() << " wins this match." << endl;
                        cout << endl;
                        player1Wins += 1;
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    //Player 2 wins
                    else {
                        cout << player2.GetName() << " wins this match." << endl;
                        cout << endl;
                        player2Wins += 1;
                        valid = false;
                    }
                }
                //Re-enter player 2 choice
                else { 
                    cout << "Invalid entry. Try again." << endl;
                    cout << "Enter 0 for rock, 1 for paper, 2 for scissors, 3 to quit" << endl;
                    cout << "Enter player 2 choice: " << endl;
                    cin >> player2Choice;
                    if (player2Choice == 3) {
                        valid = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            //Print match result
        player1.SetPlayerWins(player1Wins);
        player1.SetPlayerLosses(gameCount, playerTies);
        player2.SetPlayerWins(player2Wins);
        player2.SetPlayerLosses(gameCount, playerTies);
        player.PrintMatchInfo(player1, player2);
        }
        //Re-enter player 1 choice
        else {
            cout << "Invalid entry. Try again." << endl;
        }
        //Start new match
        cout << "Enter 0 for rock, 1 for paper, 2 for scissors, 3 to quit" << endl;
        cout << "Enter player 1 choice: " << endl;
        cin >> player1Choice;
        valid = true;
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly, except when you input an invalid number for player2, and then input 3 to quit right after, it won't quit. This is the output.

```
Enter 0 for rock, 1 for paper, 2 for scissors, 3 to quit
Enter player 1 choice:
0
Enter player 2 choice:
4
Invalid entry. Try again.
Enter 0 for rock, 1 for paper, 2 for scissors, 3 to quit
Enter player 2 choice:
3
Enter 0 for rock, 1 for paper, 2 for scissors, 3 to quit
Enter player 1 choice:
```

It should look like this:

```
Enter 0 for rock, 1 for paper, 2 for scissors, 3 to quit
Enter player 1 choice:
0
Enter player 2 choice:
4
Invalid entry. Try again.
Enter 0 for rock, 1 for paper, 2 for scissors, 3 to quit
Enter player 2 choice:
3

The players have played 0 round(s) and they tied.
```

Originally I didn't have the second if branch for player2 to choose 3 beneath the invalid choice option. I added that because choosing an invalid choice, then choosing 3 to quit, came up with invalid choice again instead of quitting. The only thing that the change did was to make it skip back to the beginning to player1 choice. Choosing 3 the first time does cause it to quit. And choosing an invalid choice and then 3 for player1 also causes it to quit. I've run out of ideas.

Comment: You've left out the parts where you define the variables etc. Please show a [mre] so that we can compile your program without having to assume anything. Cudos for including the actual input and output as well as the expected output though. It will make it very likely that someone will help you once you've updated the question to include code that we can compile.

Comment: I added the rest of the relevant code, thanks.

Comment: The general problem is that you stuffed all of this code in `main` instead of breaking it up into functions.  There is a lot of redundant code, where if you made those functions, would reduce `main` down to just a few lines, and thus would make the logic much more easier to handle.

Comment: You have two levels of while-loops. A `break` will only get out of the inner level.

Comment: One obvious problem is that the header guard in `Player.h` is lacking an `#endif` at the end of the file. Please also look into how to make this into a **minimal** reproducible example.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: **Never** do `using namespace <anything>;` in the global namespace in header files. It pollutes the global namespace for everyone including your header files.

Comment: Ted- I'm a student and this is for an assignment. My instructor expects us to use using namespace std. I've added the endif as instructed. Paul, I cleaned up some of the reduntant code, do you see more? BoP, do you have a suggestion to get it to break out of the outer loop as well?

Comment: _"My instructor expects us to use `using namespace std`"_ - That's fine if you do it sparingly and with caution inside the implementation files (the `.cpp` files). If your instructor wants you to do it in the global namespace in header files, your instructor is teaching you bad habits. Code like that will never be accepted in the real world.

Comment: BoP...you were right, I didn't need a second while loop. I removed it and the problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: Ted, I don't think he specifically said to use it in the header files, that was all me. I removed it from the header and added it to the cpp files. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two levels of while-loops. A break will only get out of the inner level. –
BoP
19 mins ago
Removed the second unnecessary while loop. Problem is solved